# Как определить, является ли файл символической ссылкой?

Tags: java, android, файлы, symlinks

Как определить, является ли файл символической ссылкой? В андроиде.
Java NIO не предлагать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот можно использовать код, который определяет  канонический путь к родительскому каталогу, а не к самому файлу. Это не дает 100% гарантии, что несоответствие связано с символической ссылкой, но это хороший признак того, что файл нуждается в специальной обработке.

```
public static boolean isSymlink(File file) throws IOException {
  if (file == null)
    throw new NullPointerException("File must not be null");
  File canonical;
  if (file.getParent() == null) {
    canonical = file;
  } else {
    File canonicalDir = file.getParentFile().getCanonicalFile();
    canonical = new File(canonicalDir, file.getName());
  }
  return !canonical.getCanonicalFile().equals(canonical.getAbsoluteFile());
}
```

Ну и конечно вариант *nix way:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"test", "-h", yourFileName});
p.waitFor();
if (p.exitValue() == 0) 
   //символическая ссылка
else
   //не символическая ссылка
```

## upd#1 Автор задал вопрос почему нельзя сделать так?

```
public static boolean containsSymlink(File file) {
  return !file.getCanonicalFile().equals(file.getAbsoluteFile());
}
```

Этот код вернет `true`, если  ли какой-либо компонент в пути файла будет тоже символической ссылкой. А приведенный выше код метода `isSymlink(File file)` вернет `true`, если только последний компонент в пути файла является символической ссылкой ...

Для большего понимания можно привести пример вывода строк для файла с помощью `getAbsolutePath()`, `getAbsoluteFile()`, `getCanonicalPath()` и `getCanonicalFile()`.

```
name:file1.txt 
is directory:false 
exists:true 
path:..\testing\file1.txt 
absolute file:C:\projects\workspace\testing\..\testing\file1.txt 
absolute path:C:\projects\workspace\testing\..\testing\file1.txt 
canonical file:C:\projects\workspace\testing\file1.txt 
canonical path:C:\projects\workspace\testing\file1.txt
```

Comment: Скажите, а почему не достаточно просто этого:`return !file.getCanonicalFile().equals(file.getAbsoluteFile());
}`

Comment: @Andreyua Вот по этой причине `notice that getAbsolutePath() returns an absolute path, but that this path can contain things like "." and ".."`, а `getAbsoluteFile()` -  это равносильно `new File(getAbsolutePath()) `

Comment: getParent и getParentFile чем-то отличаются?

Comment: @Andreyua, Qwertiy  смотрите upd#1

Comment: Наведите пример по компоненты, не могу вас толком понять. Мне нужно ли лишь удостовериться , является ли файл символьной ссылкой, то бишь. Если сделать напр. ls /symlink.xxx -la , то будет в начале строки будет стоять буква l (символическая сслыка или же другая буква (не с. ссылка)

Comment: Насчёт рунтайма, вроде у вас ошибка: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test.` -L file` — истина, если file существует и является символьной ссылкой.

Comment: @Andreyua https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(Unix) - тут уже сами решайте, что вам использовать. Ошибки нет.

Comment: Вьехал , прочтя это:http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/whats-the-difference-between-a-files-path-absolute-path-and-canonical-path.html . Получается , если absolutepath  и каноникал паз - отличаются , то не необязательно это означает , что файл является символьной ссылкой, если только не осуществить махинации как в примере от апачей.

Comment: @Andreyua Верно поняли =) Вроде в upd#1 я понятно написал, не так ли?

Comment: 1. В очередной раз подтвердилось, что русские вики не точны. 2. В апд. все понятно становится после рабочего примера , как по моей ссылке :)

Comment: Вы апдейт все таки измените, как по мне он немного запутанный и неверный.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62672/discussion-between-lex-hobbit-and-andreyua).

Comment: Я же в чате написал, что метод containsSymlink вернёт true, при 'absolute file:C:\projects\workspace\testing\..\testing\file1.txt 
canonical file:C:\projects\workspace\testing\file1.txt ввиду того, что пути не равны друг другу'. То есть, это означает - этот файл содержит симлинк?, ответ - да. Но какие тут симлинки, извините... Я бы на вашем месте, исправил эти объяснения об "компонентах файл". Как вообще компонент пути файла может быть симлинком, что '...' - могут быть симлинком. Там все алогично. Или же объясните , что вы подразумеваете под компонентом пути.